# A one-word substitute for someone who is a "news freak"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word that describes a person who is very interested in reading newspapers, and very interested in political news? Moreover one who loves being "updated" on the current affairs of the world?

Comment: It's not one word, but I have often encountered the two-word phrase "news *junky*".

Comment: Hi Krishna. You've been a user for 3 years. Please learn to tag responsibly. It's a rare question that merits 4 tags. For this question, one would suffice.

Comment: @DanBron: Good one, but `Junkie` isn't big here in India. Krishna is better off with news-freak. Just saying.

Comment: @Krrishna: Please clarify. Are you looking for a positive term to show someone in good light? Or do you wish to insult/make fun of someone?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I added the 3 tags to the question. One being the SWR tag. Very often you will see more experienced users than I adding a 4th and a 5th tag to questions. Tags need to be relevant, and IMO only one tag is not enough. I'd look at other questions tagged as SWR and see how many other tags they have before stating it is "rare".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm not saying a 5 tag worthy question doesn't exist, but in this case I think a single-word request tag suffices. But of course, I didn't know it was you. Please feel free to add them back if you wish. It's just that I look for unanswered questions by tag, and sometimes it can be confusing.

Comment: The most important tag is SWR, but because there are literally thousands of questions tagged as such, I think an extra tag doesn't do any harm. The OP is free to agree or disagree, let Krishna decide for ‘themself’ :)

Comment: @area: I want to praise someone to have this unique hobby

Comment: @KrishnaChandraTiwari: That's what I thought. I take it this term is meant for a friend of yours in an informal setting. If so, Andrey's `newsophile` works beautifully, imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a real word currently, popular culture would understand the word "newsophile"
The attachment of phile to make words like "audiophile" is becoming pretty popular creating new words over time.

Comment: [*Journophile*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZD-15SNAD-QC&q=journophile&dq=journophile&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o_9MVaitM9W3yASBnYHoBg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA) also.

Comment: or eidiseisophile from the greek word for news. (-phile is also from greek) i think i may be coining a whole new word here just as you are.

Answer (score -1):

News or current event  enthusiast ...
sorry its not one word